# jquery find children and echo all their values

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a code as you can see below. I am trying to find the html() of each span item under a certain div
for example: the div `#hello` should return :"this is" and "a nice" and  "block of spans"
html as follow:

```
<div id="hello">
<span id="info1"> this is</span>
<span id="info2">a nice</span>
<span id="info3"> block of spans</span>
</div>

<div id="bye">
<span id="info4"> more</span>
<span id="info5"> spans</span>
</div>
```

and this is the jquery I tried:

```
<script>
function values() {
var poo=$('div#hello').find('span').html();
alert(poo);

    }
</script>
```

the issue with the code I have is that it only does an alert for the first value "this is"
I need it to do an alert for all of the values. any suggestions ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each` like this to get html of each span element:

```
function values() {
  $('#hello > span').each(function(){
     alert($(this).html());
  });
}
```

Comment: @fogsy: I thought you will be able to make it. Anyways I had to create a working example for you: http://jsbin.com/arumat. See its code and how it is done. Hope that clarifies now.

Comment: quick question, what would I do if I wanted to use find() ? the ids are not directly under the div,there are 2 divs before the spans.thats the reason why it didnt work initially

Comment: @fogsy: Replace `$('#hello > span').each` with `$('#hello').find('span').each` or simply use `$('#hello span').each`

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('div#hello').find('span').each(function() {
            var aaa = $(this).html();
            alert(aaa);
           });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hello")​.find("span")​.each(function(i){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
);
```